# django - AbstractUser atributes gone ....?

Tags: django, django-models

so for some reason i get this error :

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from auctions.models import *
>>> u = User.objects.all()
>>> u
<QuerySet [<User: bob>]>
>>> u.id
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'
```

i did not set any primary key to overwrite djabgo's defaults (this is the code..)

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.username}"
```

what is going on ???

Comment: This is a `QuerySet` of `User`s, hence `.id` makes no sense, since a `QuerySet` is a *collection* of `User`s: it can contain zero, one or more users. So if you query `.id`, what would the answer be? If there are no items, it is completely unclear, if there are multiple, any would fit, so it would make the result unpredicatble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have a *`QuerySet`* of `User`s. You can see a `QuerySet` as a (lazy) *collection*. It is a collection that will be retrieved from the database. The collection can contain zero, one, or more `User` objects.

Since it is a *collection*, it makes no sense that it has a `.id` attribute. If the collection is empty, then what would the `.id` of that collection mean? If it has multiple elements, what `.id` should be returned? Furthermore since it is unknown home many records it will contain, it thus makes no sense that it would "inherit" the attributes of the model object(s) it wraps.

You can for example retrieve the *first* `User` in the `QuerySet` with:

```
u = User.objects.first()
print(u.id)
```

This works since [**`.first()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first) will here return a `User` *object*, or `None` if it can not find any. If it thus finds a record, `u` will be a `User` object, and that `User` object will have a `.id` attribute.